# Reducing a feature collection over features instead of columns

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I created a feature collection where features are grid cells, columns are monthly images and the values represent pixel area. I would like to find the mean for each feature over all columns. I tried to use `reduceColumns` but I get the mean for each column rather than for each feature.

script:

```
//----load image collection, filter, and create an image with multiple bands

var datasetAll = ee.ImageCollection(MODIS/006/MCD64A1)
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2000-01-01', '2019-12-31'))
                  .filterBounds(border);

var DSall1B = datasetAll.select('BurnDate')

var DSallImage = DSall1B.toBands()

 //----filtering grid to the area

 var grid1degreeF = grid1degree.filterBounds(border);

//----creating a layer where pixels value are the pixel area in m^2

var DSallValue1 = DSallImage.where(DSallImage, 1)

var DSallAPP1 = DSallValue1.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea())

//----summing area in each grid cell over all bands

var DSallAPP1d1 = DSallAPP1.reduceRegions({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  collection: grid1degreeF,
  scale: 500,
  });
```

Here are my assets:

border- https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/stavo/amazon_border_harvard

grid- https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/stavo/Vectorgrid_1degree

This is where I got so far. I end up with the feature collection I described before and now I wish to get the mean for each cell over all columns (dates).

This is the method I tried:

```
var properties = DSallAPP1.bandNames();

var means = DSallAPP1d1
.filter(ee.Filter.notNull(properties))
.reduceColumns({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean().repeat(229),
  selectors: properties
});
```

After calculating the means I was planning to use reduceToImage so I can end up with an image of the area means over time divided into grid cells. I assume that my method is not the most efficient one. Please advise how to calculate the means or how to approach the issue differently.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not complete sure what you're looking for here. This calculates the mean monthly area with fires, per feature:

```
var monthlyFires = datasetAll
  .select('BurnDate')
  .map(function (image) { return image.mask() })
  .mean() 

var monthlyAreaPerRegion = monthlyFires
  .multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea())
  .reduceRegions({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    collection:  grid1degree.filterBounds(border),
    scale: 500
  })

var areaImage = ee.ImageCollection(
  monthlyAreaPerRegion.map(function (feature) {
    return ee.Image(feature.getNumber('sum'))
      .clip(feature.geometry())
      .int32()
  })
).mosaic().clip(border.geometry())

print(monthlyAreaPerRegion)
Map.addLayer(areaImage, {min: 0, max: 260000000, palette: 'green, yellow, red'})
Map.centerObject(areaImage)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/108c70867336b09657283e56811c5140

Comment: Thank you for your effort Daniel! I have no experience with functions so far so I don't completely understand it. However, the result I am getting here is a dictionary with the means of each month. What I was after is an image/feature collection with the **means of each grid cell (features, not columns)**. To get to the means of columns I could have simply used the _reduceColumns_ function

Comment: So, you're looking for mean area burnt during your date range, per feature?

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: The script is working but it is still not the desired result. If I understand correctly, you are doing a mean over the mask values of each pixel and then multiply by an area image to receive a mean area per pixel. later you sum up the pixels according to the grid cells. I would like to do a mean of the area sum in **each grid cell** (not each pixel), since I will be using different grid sizes and I would also like to **exclude** from the mean **months in which there were no fires at all**. Also, could the solution be related to `aggregate_mean`?